# Customizing UISlider to handle touch that started outside

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, event-handling, uikit, uislider

I would like to start a touch outside of a `UISlider` (in its superview), and when the touch moves onto the `UISlider`, slide it like normal. How should I implement this?

Comment: Do you mean that when the touch moves onto the slider's thumb you want to start sliding?  A slider ignores a touch that starts on the slider's track outside its thumb.

Comment: @robmayoff Yes, I want to start sliding whenever the touch moves onto the thumb, regardless of where the touch started. (Either elsewhere in the `UISlider`, or in the superview.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make your superview this custom class and connect the `slider` outlet to your slider. It should do what you need, barring any custom tracking you might have on the slider itself. This probably doesn't play well with any gesture recognizers on the superview (e.g., if the superview is a scroll view, all bets are off).

This also blindly ignores other views in the superview that might need to respond to touches. If you finer-grain control, update `hitTest:forEvent:` and only return MyView or the slider when appropriate.

```
@interface MyView : UIView
{
    BOOL _tracking;
}
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UISlider *slider;
@end

@implementation MyView
@synthesize slider;

-(UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UIView *superAnswer = [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
    if( [superAnswer isEqual:self.slider] ) {
        return( superAnswer );
    }
    else {
        return( self );
    }
}

-(void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *aTouch = [touches anyObject];
    if( [self.slider pointInside:[aTouch locationInView:self.slider] withEvent:event] ) {
        if( _tracking ) {
            [self.slider continueTrackingWithTouch:aTouch withEvent:event];
        }
        else {
            [self.slider beginTrackingWithTouch:aTouch withEvent:event];
            _tracking = YES;
        }
    }
    else {
        if( _tracking ) {
            [self.slider endTrackingWithTouch:aTouch withEvent:event];
            _tracking = NO;
        }
    }
}
@end
```

Comment: The `...TrackingWithTouch` methods was what I was looking for. Previously I was using a similar setup, except I was trying to pass along `touches...` events. Now it works. Thanks!